# Why getPopupContainer doesn't work correctly in my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm getting this warning:

> Warning: [antd: Modal] Static function can not consume context like dynamic theme. Please use 'App' component instead.

Then, the `Modal.confirm()` doesn't show correctly because it renders outside of the dependency tree and doesn't inherit the styles.

I'm using react 18.2.0 and antd 5.4.6.

Here I leave the code

main.tsx

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
     <ThemeWrapper>
         <Outlet />
      </ThemeCoWrapper>
  </Suspense>
);
```

```
const ThemeWrapper: React.FC<ThemeProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<any>(defaultTheme);

  const modalContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={theme}
      getPopupContainer={() => modalContainerRef.current as HTMLElement}
    >
      <div ref={modalContainerRef}>{children}</div>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
};

export default ThemeWrapper;
```

Example of function in which I use the Modal.confirm() inside the wrapper

```
const onLogout = () => {
    Modal.confirm({
      title: (
        <b>
          {intl.formatMessage({
            id: 'labelCloseSession',
          })}
        </b>
      ),
      content: intl.formatMessage({
        id: 'labelLogoutConfirm',
      }),
      centered: true,
      onOk: async () => {
        try {
          await loginService.logout();
          removeUserSession();
          globalContext.dispatch({
            type: GlobalStateActionType.LOGOUT,
          });
          navigate('/login');
        } catch (error) {}
      },
    });
  };
```

I tried to use `document.getElemetById` instead of `useRef` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because static function in React 18 concurrent mode will not well support. In v5, Antd recommends to use hooks for the static replacement [(read here)](https://ant.design/components/app#when-to-use). So, you will need to set up your project like what they stated here: https://ant.design/components/app#basic-usage

In your case, try:

- For the `ThemeWrapper` component
- `import { App } from 'antd';`
- And then, wrap the `<div>` element in `<App></App>` like:

  ```js
  <ConfigProvider
       theme={theme}
       getPopupContainer={() => modalContainerRef.current as HTMLElement}
  >
       <App>
           <div ref={modalContainerRef}>{children}</div>
       </App>
  </ConfigProvider>
  ```

Here, I provide the codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/text-and-link-component-antd-5-0-2-forked-9svf8v?file=/demo.tsx
They recommend encapsulating App at the top level in the application

After that, you will need to use `modal.confirm({})` from `App.useApp();` instead of the old `Modal.confirm()` in your `onLogout` function.