# Upgrade from antd 4 to 5: theme prop in ConfigProvider causes warning

Tags: antd

I am currently upgrading a React 18.2.0 app from antd 4.x to antd 5.x.

As soon as I add the `theme` prop to the `ConfigProvider` I get this warning:

*Warning: [antd: message] Static function can not consume context like dynamic theme. Please use 'App' component instead.*

This is roughly the code:

```
import { ConfigProvider, App } from 'antd';
import { Content } from '@components/Content'

const MyApp: React.FC = memo(() => {
    return (
        <ConfigProvider
            locale={de}
            theme={{
                token: {
                    borderRadius: 0
                }
            }}
        >
            <App>               
              <Content />   
            </App>
        </ConfigProvider>
    );
});

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76151754/9894625) helps you?